# Not sure how to evaluate this series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Stumped on this absolute convergence problem!  (Converge conditionally, absolutely, or diverges)

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)} $$

First, I try to do the absolute convergence test:
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left\lvert \frac{-1^n}{\ln(n)}\right\rvert = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n)} $$

Not sure how to evaluate this series.  Which test to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series fulfills the conditions of Leibniz alternating series and then it converges, but it doesn't converge absolutely since by comparison

$$\frac1{\log n}\ge\frac1n$$

and the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: What's the most intuitive way to know that $ln(n) < n$ ?    Or directly that $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{ln(n)}$    Exponent for e to get 10 is way smaller than 10.  So, ln(10) < 10.   ie:  ln(n) < n

Comment: @JackOfAll Evaluate, for example with l'Hospital, the limit $\;\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^\epsilon}\;$ , for *any* $\;\epsilon>0\;$ . You'll see at once that the limit is zero, so that for $\;x\;$ big enough you have that inequality.

Comment: How do you algebraically go from $ln(n) < n   $  to $\frac{1}{ln(n)} > \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: For $\;n>2\;,\;\;\log n>0\;$ , so $\;\log n<n\iff\frac1{\log n}>\frac1n\;$ . This is simply inequalities and fractions.

Comment: Just because $log(n )> 0$, why can you assume $log( n) < n$ ?

Comment: @JackOfAll I already addressed that doubt where I wrote about the limits. This should be very basic stuff for someone doing series.

Comment: @JackOfAll With all due respect, are you taking a basic calculus course? Because this basic stuff is usually taught before series.  And if the limit of $\;\frac{\log x}x\;$ is zero, then from some value of $\;x\;$ on you'll have $$\frac{\log x}x<1\implies \log x<x$$

Comment: No, my issue is how you would ever think to even introduce the idea of that limit when you're doing a simple comparison of $\frac{1}{log(n)}$ to $\frac{1}{n}$   Seems insanely convoluted just to demonstrate a "self-evident" basic inequality.  I am assuming there is a much simpler and intuitive way than setting up l'Hospitals with completely different expressions

Comment: @JackOfAll The "self evident" idea must be based on firm soil to be really "that evident", and the use of limits makes this in a rather simple and fast way.

Answer (score 3):

You know that for $n\ge 1$, $\ln(n) \le n$ which in turn says that $\frac{1}{n}\le \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$. What does this tell you about the absolute convergence?

As for conditional, think about the alternating series test.

Comment: Well since you're doing series, I would think you've done derivatives. You can easily show that $x-\ln(x)$ is increasing by taking a derivative and doing some basic manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

do you know alternated series ?

you can also group the terms by two, and find that $$\frac{1}{\ln (2 n)}  - \frac{1}{\ln (2 n+1)} = \frac{\ln (2 n+1) - \ln (2 n)}{\ln (2n) \ln (2n+1)} =  \frac{\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)}{\ln (2n) \ln (2n+1)} \sim \frac{1}{2n \ln^2 n}$$

and $\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{1}{n \ln^2 n}$ is by the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), or the integral test, an absolutely convergent Bertrand series.